# Is it the class that slows down the game?

Tags: java, slick, frame-rate

My framerate lastime exceeds 1000 now the highest is 15. I have thousands lines of code in one class(I was still fresh last time and did not think of putting it in another class) Is it the class that makes the game slower?

Comment: This is impossible for anyone to answer with the information you've provided, the size of the class is irrelevant. What matters is the code being called. Have you read the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) yet? I've asked multiple times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How to **identify** the issue:

To find out what is slowing down your game (also known as bottleneck), you could use Profiling.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29

It is not classes that slow down frame rate, it is the amount of processing time it takes to complete the instructions in the code (for instance instructions that reside inside functions).

Using Profiling could help you check how much time is spent running each function and how many times each function is being ran.

Here are some suggestions on how to use Profiling with Java:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422289/any-recommended-java-profiling-tutorial

Then you would know for sure what is slowing the code down.

How to **improve** speed:

After you find the part of the code that is causing the slowdown, consider how to refactor the code. You may need to consult others or you might find out that you could use the resources in a new efficient way for the same result.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring

Comment: How do I fasten it up?

Comment: @SystemNetworks Remove the bottlenecks. There is no single answer for that.

Comment: There is no 'magic answer' that will make code run faster. You simply identify the parts of the code that consumes the most processing time and think of ways to improve those parts for better efficiency.

Comment: @ArthurWulfWhite If you insist on answering questions that are off topic, you should at least make them community wiki. Answering questions that are off topic encourages users like SystemNetworks to continue to ask questions that are off topic, since they know they'll get an answer anyway.

Comment: @Byte56 What is community wiki? I see what you mean. I do not think ignoring him is the answer.

Comment: @ArthurWulfWhite When you make your answer, check the community wiki check box in the bottom right. If we didn't ignore the off topic questions, people could ask whatever they wanted and get an answer. Just my thoughts.

Comment: @Byte56 That makes sense.